# How come Linq functions are available on a variable which can be of a type string

Tags: .net, linq, string, linq-to-objects

Please help me with this question. I thought that Linq works on a collection or an array. How come Linq works on a single string variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ To Objects works primarily on [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), the canonical interface for sequences of a specified type. [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<char>`, meaning that it can be viewed as a sequence of characters.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class String : IComparable, 
    ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, 
    IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
```

LINQ itself is a *pattern*, more than anything. It's not restricted to `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the one nor the other. LINQ (to objects) consists of a set of extension methods that operate on `IEnumerable<T>` and/or `IQueryable<T>`.
because the `string` type implements `IEnumerable<char>`, `string` is accessible to LINQ methods.

Thomas